# How to connect MWAA CLI that is hosted in a public subnet

Tags: jwt, airflow, airflow-2.x, mwaa, airflow-api

I am trying to invoke airflow Cli from my local terminal and I have followed these instruction https://dnx.solutions/how-to-use-apache-airflow-cli-with-amazon-mwaa/

and created cli_token and executed

```bash
curl \
  --request POST "https://$WEB_SERVER_HOSTNAME/aws_mwaa/cli" \
  --header "Authorization: Bearer $CLI_TOKEN" \
  --header "Content-Type: text/plain" \
  --data-raw list_dags
```

But I am getting an error:

```
curl: (35) OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to aws_mwaa:443
```

How can I overcome this error?